# opencv addweighted callback function not working well inside a class

Tags: c++, opencv

when I use ordinary functions the callback works well and the code works fine, so I decided to put the functions inside a class and this is where are problem begins. At first I was having a syntax error "error non-standard syntax; use '&' to create a pointer to member", so I change the function to a static function, the next error was "error: uninitialized local "variable" blean(blean is an object) used", so I created a constructor and initialized the variable to zero, now the code runs but the call back function isn't changing the value, even though the trackbar is moving......

```
header file-----

   class Blending
{
public:

    Blending();

     static void Blend(int, void*);

     int Blended;
  double alpha;
     double beta;
       int  key;
      int minimumvalue;
      int maximumvalue ;

};


cpp file-----



    int maximumvalue = 100;
    int minimumvalue;
    void Blending:: Blend(int, void*)
    {
        Blending b;

        b.alpha = (double)b.minimumvalue/ 100;
        addWeighted(img,b.alpha,img2, 1.0 - b.alpha, 0, des);
        imshow("Blendimage", des);
    }


    int main()
    {



        Blending bl;
        bl.Blend(bl.minimumvalue, 0);
        createTrackbar("Blend", "Blendimage", &minimumvalue, maximumvalue, bl.Blend);
        waitKey(0);
        //imshow("Blendimage", des),waitKey(0);
        return 0;
    }
```

I have looked through some similar questions on the site  but haven't found any  solution to my problem, and I guess it is just a silly error from my side, thanks in advance any criticism is accepted ...

Comment: Inside Blend function you create an object b that is initialized with default values so alpha is always equal to 0.

Comment: really so how do I go about it, I kind of getting confused

Comment: I tried doing this Blending::Blending() :alpha(2){} but still no improvement..